# validation function not being called on submit but gets called on delete

Tags: forms

My validation function gets called when *'deleting'* the node but isn't getting called while *'submitting'* the form. Moreover, the function works perfectly when tested on the offline copy of my site. That means there is no problem with the function.

I first tried *'field validation module'* on my production site which too was working smoothly on the offline copy of my site but disappointed on the production site. And now same is the story with my custom validation function.

Can this be rules or some other setting which is causing the issue??

Please help!

Comment: First, clear all caches on production site. Then, provide the code which doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the sad part is that clearing the caches isn't helping :(